# breadth of join-semilattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

On page 16, *Lattice Theory: Foundation*, George Grätze(2011),

> 1.19 Show that a join-semilattice $(L; \lor)$ has breadth at most $n$, for a
>   positive integer n, iff for every nonempty finite subset $X$ of $L$, there
>   exists a nonempty $Y \subseteq X$ with at most $n$ elements such that $$\bigvee X = \bigvee Y$$

I don't know in which way we shall establish this equivalence by appealing to the definition of breadth, which is

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. We say that an order $P$ has breadth at most $n$
>   if for all elements $x_0, x_1, x_2,……x_n, y_0, y_1,……y_n$,in $P$, if $x_i \leq y_j$ for all $i \neq j$ in $\{0, 1, ……,n\}$, then there exists $ i \in\{0, 1, ……,n\}$,such that $x_i \leq y_i$. The breadth
>   of $P$, in notation, breadth$(P)$, is the least positive integer $n$ such that $P$ has
>   breadth at most $n$ if such an $n$ exists.
>
> Observe that this definition of breadth is **selfdual**. For an equivalent
>   denition for a join-semilattice (or for a lattice), see Exercise 1.19

Besides the aforementioned exercise, I have difficulty in visualizing this concept, breadth of an order. I don't know the meaning of selfdual, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\br}{\operatorname{breadth}}$Let’s start by assuming that for every non-empty finite $X\subseteq L$ there is a non-empty $Y\subseteq X$ such that $|Y|\le n$ and $\bigvee Y=\bigvee X$. We want to show that $\br(L)\le n$, so suppose that we have elements $x_0,\dots,x_n,y_0,\dots,y_n\in L$ such that $x_i\le y_j$ whenever $i,j\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ and $i\ne j$. We want to show that there is a $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ such that $x_k\le y_k$.

Let $X=\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$; by hypothesis there is a non-empty $Z\subseteq X$ such that $|Z|\le n$ and $\bigvee Z=\bigvee X$. Since $|Z|\le n$, there is a $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ such that $x_k\notin Z$. For each $x_i\in Z$ we have $i\ne k$ and therefore $x_i\le y_k$, so $x_k\le\bigvee X=\bigvee Z\le y_k$, and we’re done: $x_k\le y_k$.

You can prove the other direction by induction on $|X|$. Assume that $\br(L)\le n$. It’s certainly true that if $|X|\le n$, then there is a non-empty $Y\subseteq X$ such that $|Y|\le n$ and $\bigvee Y=\bigvee X$: just take $Y=X$.

Now suppose that $|X|=n+1$, and let $X=\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$. For $j\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ let $$y_j=\bigvee \left(X\setminus\{x_j\}\right)\;;$$ clearly this definition ensures that $x_i\le y_j$ whenever $i,j\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ and $i\ne j$. Since $\br(L)\le n$, there is a $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ such that $x_k\le y_k$ for some $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$. Then $$x_k\le\bigvee\left(X\setminus\{x_k\}\right)\;,$$ so $$\bigvee X=\bigvee\left(X\setminus\{x_k\}\right)\;,$$ and we can take $Y=X\setminus\{x_k\}$.

Now suppose that $m>n+1$, and for each non-empty $X\subseteq L$ with $|X|<m$ there is a non-empty $Y\subseteq X$ such that $|Y|\le n$ and $\bigvee Y=\bigvee X$. Let $X$ be a subset of $L$ of cardinality $m$; we show that there is a non-empty $Y\subseteq X$ such that $|Y|\le n$ and $\bigvee Y=\bigvee X$. Fix $x\in X$, and let $X_0=X\setminus\{x\}$. By the induction hypothesis there is an $X_1\subseteq X_0$ such that $|X_1|\le n$ and $\bigvee X_1=\bigvee X_0$. Let $X_2=X_1\cup\{x\}$. Clearly $\bigvee X_2=\bigvee X$, so if $|X_2|\le n$, we’re done. Otherwise, $|X_2|=n+1$, and we just proved the result for that case. The theorem now follows by induction.

---

To say that the definition of *breadth* is selfdual is to say that replacing the definition by its dual does not change the concept. The definition of breadth:

> An order $P$ has *breadth* at most $n$ if for all elements $x_0,\dots,x_n,y_n,\dots,y_n\in P$, if $x_i\le y_j$ for all $i,j\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ with $i\ne j$, then there is a $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ such that $x_k\le y_k$.

The dual definition:

> An order $P$ has *dual-breadth* at most $n$ if for all elements $x_0,\dots,x_n,y_n,\dots,y_n\in P$, if $x_i\ge y_j$ for all $i,j\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ with $i\ne j$, then there is a $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ such that $x_k\ge y_k$.

If you interchange $x_i$ and $y_i$ for each $i\in\{0,\dots,n\}$, you transform each of these definitions into the other. Thus, they actually say the same thing and define the same concept: what I called *dual-breadth* is just breadth.

Comment: Thank you very much,sir!It's amazing (from my persepective) that the self-duality is far less obvious in the alternative defintion.

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace: You’re welcome. (And I have to agree about it being less obvious in the form.)